# Помогите составить запрос на Doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

```
class Company {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="ID")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Sector")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="CompanySectors",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="CompanyID", referencedColumnName="ID")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="SectorID", referencedColumnName="ID")}
     *      )
     * */
    protected $sectors;

}

class Sector {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="ID")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

Есть 2 класса Company и Sector 
Задача: Составить запрос на Doctrine 2 который вытягивает все компании у которых SectorID =1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется надо добавить конструктор в первом классе и присвоить $sectors ArrayCollection.

```
$qb->select('c')
   ->from('Company','c')
   ->innerJoin('c.sectors','s')
   ->where($qb->expr()->eq('s.id', 1))
```

Далее если нужно сам dql просто сделать

```
(string)$qb
```